# embedding video using iframe

Tags: iframe, embed

When using iframe, how do I get just the video to show, not the rest of the page? Here is my code:

```
height="550" width="800" 
src="http://www.streetfire.net/video/f1-monza-practice-in-car-2011-pt-2_2428117.htm">
```

I had to take the iframe markers off the front and back to post the link.

What else do I need to improve this code? I am on the verge of starting a website but would like to post my videos with just the video showing. The current embed code that Streetfire.net uses will not link to my Squarespace account. Squarespace only seems to like iframe embedding.

Thanks in advance,

Kurlee Daddee

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access full screen mode you just need to add it to the iframe

```
<iframe  id="home_modal_iframe"  width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
```